# Non-editing author permissions Google Calendar

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I have a web application that allows users to sign in with their Google Account and create events on a Google Calendar. However, I only want one specific user to edit/delete already existing events in the calendar and all other users should only be able to add events to the Calendar.

A permission similar to this exists on Outlook, which has a permission called Non-editing author. Is the same available for Google Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

both the events.insert and the events.update / events.patch require the scope of

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar read/write access to Calendars

Which technically gives a user access to read and write to any part of the calendar not just the events.   Your application is going to have to limit access the calendar api does not give you this ability.